# How to calculate totals from selected checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, master-pages, repeater

I am using ASP.NET with a masterpage.  Within it I have a nested repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID=rptAttribute runat=server>
<ItemTemplate>
<h3><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description") %></h3>
<div id="labelbox">
  <asp:TextBox ID="tSecionTotal" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  <div id="key1">
     <asp:Repeater ID="rptKey" runat="server">
       <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:CheckBox ID="rptKeySelection" runat="server" />
        <span><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description") %></span>
       </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:Repeater>
  </div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I am wanting to calculate the values of the checkboxes within EACH section and make two displays.

1. Have the textbox field (tSecionTotal) update with the value(s) from the checkboxes.
2. Have an total text/label update with an overall total.

HTML rendered looks something like this:

> Opened and closed the interaction appropriately 
>   [ -- textbox to display total of this section -- ]
>
> []Was not ready to take the interaction [+1]
>  
>   []Did not use proper opening [+1]
>   []Did not ensure that there were no other needs [+2]
>  
>   []Did not close the interaction in an appropriate manner [+5]> 
>   
>   Demonstrated common courtesy (polite, patient, empathetic)
>  
>   [ -- textbox to display total of this section -- ]
>
> []Did not use common courteously words (please, thank you) [+1]
>   []Inappropriate voice level / inflection with customer [+2]
>   []Inappropriately interrupts customer [+5]
>   []Did not demonstrate empathy when needed [+2]
>
> Adapted to the customer's level of knowledge and expertise
>   [ -- textbox to display total of this section -- ]
>
> []Did not provide clear instructions (how to) [+1]
>   []Did not provide clear instructions (how to) [+1]
>   []Did not provide clear explanation / education (why we are doing this) [+3]
>   []Did not provide clear explanation / education (why we are doing this) [+5]
>
> Overall Totals [ -- textbox to display overall total -- ]

Answer (score 2):

You can find all checked, then the values of the items, add them and place it on total

```
var Total = 0;
$("input:checked").each(function(i, selected){ 
  Total+= $(selected).parent(".keydiv").find(".myVal").val();
});
```

What I do here is to find all check box, then for each check box I go to find the souround it element (eg the `class=keydiv`), then I found inside the children of tr the element that have the value you won to add, I suppose that have the css="myVal".

Let say that if you render it like that.

```
<div id="key1" class="keydiv">
  check box
  <span class="myVal">5</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I assume the .myVal in my example would be the Div ID "key1"  Is that right? I guess I still dont know what you mean since I dont have any TR tags in my repeater.  Also how do I bind this to the textbox that is within the parent repeater?

Comment: @user1178691 I am not sure about your struct, ok, I change the tr with div and class see it. To find the correct struct, you need to place the html as rendered.